# Remote desktop on Debian 9 with cinnamon desktop

Tags: debian, vnc, rdp

I have two machines:

1 - $Clients:

dual-boot of

- Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon 64-bit
- Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

on a laptop.

2 - $Server:

- GNU/Linux Debian 9 Cinnamon 64-bit

**I would like to connect from $Clients to the $Server via Remote desktop to view the main desktop.**

Rationale: I opt for RDP protocol because it is integrated both in Windows and Linux (`rdesktop`).

But hey: It could be VNC for what it matters, I just need to replace the slow TeamViewer with a local connection to server's desktop.

Note: The server is usually running headless, but now I need to do several time-consuming things in the Desktop environment.

I personally used both VNC and RDP when I used Windows, so I have experience with them, but what all do I have to do for this to work on Linux is so far a mystery to me. I googled many guides, but they all differ more or less. And that's where you step in, I hope for a coherent answer to guide me with all aspects.

Comment: Non an answer to your question, but you don't need RDP.  It's easier (and to some point safer) to use SSH with X11 forwarding.  You need an X server on Windows to open remote windows on $Server over SSH.

Comment: Were you using compression with X forwarding? That can speed up things considerably. See  http://xmodulo.com/how-to-speed-up-x11-forwarding-in-ssh.html for details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSH into debian from linux-mint

**Update**

There are some problem to connect through VNC to a remote host with cinnamon desktop using the regular way. The problem can be solved by installing `x11vnc` on the server and using `vncviewer` to connect.

Install and configure `x11vnc`:

```
apt install x11vnc
```

To configure the password for remote access :

```
x11vnc -storepasswd
```

By default the password will be stored under `~/.vnc/passwd`

To force connecting  using the password run :

```
x11vnc -rfbauth ~/.vnc/passwd
```

To connect without password run `x11vnc`.

sample output:

```
The VNC desktop is:      cinnamon:1
PORT=5901
```

To connect use the following command:

```
vncviewer ip.address:1
```

**On debian**

Install `tightvncserver` :

```
apt-get install tightvncserver
```

Then run :

```
vncserver
```

to set up your password.

Adjust your parametres :

```
vncserver :1 -geometry 1024x600 -depth 16 -pixelformat rgb565
```

**On linux mint:**

install `xtightvncviewer` :

```
apt install xtightvncviewer
```

Connect:

```
vncviewer IP-SERVER:5901
```

To exit run:

```
vncserver -kill :1
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68029/discussion-between-gad3r-and-vlastimil).

Comment: See this answer "...[from OSX (MacOS)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/356570/151544)"

Comment: Do be aware though, that passwords stored in vnc password files are limited to [8 characters](http://forum.ultravnc.info/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=15459) and  [trivially decryptable](https://github.com/jeroennijhof/vncpwd) and really shouldn't be used. See my question: [Secure way to allow sharing an Xubuntu / XFCE dektop remotely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211445/secure-way-to-allow-sharing-an-xubuntu-xfce-dektop-remotely)

Answer (score 1):

`rdesktop` is a client for Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) thus it is used to view remote Microsoft desktops so it won't be suitable for viewing your $server desktop.

[X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) was designed for sharing displays from a server to various clients - either locally or remotely. For security reasons X11 forwarding is, or should be, disabled.

So from the Linux client you can just ssh in using the `-X` or `-Y` command line arguements and then just run the window application, eg:

```
ssh -X -Y $SERVER
echo $DISPLAY
```

the `echo $DISPLAY` should return something like `myserver:10.0` so you can then just run which ever program you want on the server and it will display on your client.

If you see an error like:

```
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
```

Then you will need to edit your sshd_config file on your server, and allow `X11Forwarding` and then restart sshd.

However, this won't work out of the box on Windows unless you install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) which is why people often use VNC, as their are Windows native VNCviewers.

I have always found the [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/) a good place for guiding you through setting up [VNC](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TigerVNC) - although this guide uses TigerVNC (this available as a [debian package](https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch/tigervnc)) you can use x11vnc, or tightvnc instead of tigervnc.

The reason it might seems so confusing is that Unix was designed as a multiuser system - thus it was always assumed that each user would have their own desktop and thus the idea of a single desktop for the machine doesn't make sense - you can run a different X server and display manager for each user on the system.

hth

Comment: @Vlastimil does  `ssh -X USER@SERVER gnome-calculator ` work after xforwarding?